# Django search or filter depending on the url

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

I have a site with Django which contains multiple blogs.
I am trying to make filters by categories from the menu depending on the url:

If I'm in the home - get all the entries of a category that belong to any blog.
*url example: www.site.com/category_path/*

If I'm in a blog - get all the entries of a category that belong to the current blog.
*url example: www.site.com/blog_slug/category_path/*

I can solve this by changing the urls I call in the menu.

Example: `<a href="{% url 'blogosphere:categories:detail' category_path='music'  %}">Music</a>`

Example: `<a href="{% url 'blogosphere:blogs:categories:detail' blog_slug=blog.slug category_path='music'  %}">Music</a>`

But I would like to see if there is a more elegant way to do it.

Thank!

PD: I want to solve this for the search also.

Comment: Are you asking "is there a better way than manually writing urls for every category"?

Comment: No, I'm asking if there is any other way to do this same thing but instead of me changing the url conditionally in the template. For example if you could call a view that is in charge of the url from where I am calling to redirect or to another that makes the filter correctly or the search.